# Pod Rack Details Using Availability Zone in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I'm trying to automate a mapping between availability zone to its corresponding rackID in AWS using their Java API.

Is there a way to do this?

Basically, given an availability zone, say: "us-east-1a", the library should return "use1-az1" as the rack ID.

Answer (score 1):

The node controller does not label the node with the **partition associated with a placement group** or the rack that it is in. If you want to get that information, you'll either need to add labels to the node, e.g. GroupName=GroupA,PartitionID=5 or query the EC2 API from your application. Be aware that instances deployed into a placement group are not automatically tagged. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html for additional information.